Incorrect Article count on profile page when signed In
I've encountered a strange issue on my Stack Overflow profile.
When I am signed in, my profile for articles shows that I have 1 article under the "Articles" tab,
although I haven't written any articles. However, when I view my profile while signed out, it correctly shows 0 articles.
Here are screenshots of the issue:

When signed in:





When signed out:




I've tried using different browsers and using incognito mode, but the issue persists.
Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Do you perhaps have any deleted / draft articles?

There are not any deleted articles. Can't confirm the presence of drafts (largely  because I have no clue how to search for those)

@Zoe I once recommended an article, but it has been declined and never been published. Might that be the cause?

It wouldn't be fully unprecedented (search already misattributes posts to being written by an editor rather than OP), but I have no clue
